# how to set width to a particular cell my exported excel files with exceljs

Tags: reactjs, excel, exceljs

I am trying to set width to a particular cell of my exported excel files with exceljs

I am using this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

and when I checked there were only option to increase the column width and row height in fact I just only change width of a particular cell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.